# UnCaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for jQuery.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've been running into some problems with my jQuery plugin.  In my console, it is giving the following errors.  I'm importing jQuery from the Google CDN.  I believe that these errors are causing some Javascript on my website to not function properly.

I include my jQuery Javascript before any other Javascript.

Let me know if there is anything I can do to remedy this solution, thanks.

[image]

**In main.js:**

Line 114 (the one with $('.example-typeahead') ):

```
var data = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","American Samoa"];

$('.example-typeahead').typeahead({ items: 5, source: data });
```

Line 437:

```
uiDemo(); // Initialize Demo Code
```

Line 448:

```
/* Initialize WebApp when page loads */
$(function(){ webApp.init(); });
```

**In jquery.js:**

Code at line 7341 of jquery.js (line 7341 is the one that starts with "s[ s.length ] ="):

```
jQuery.param = function( a, traditional ) {
var prefix,
    s = [],
    add = function( key, value ) {
        // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
        value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
        s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
    };

// Set traditional to true for jQuery <= 1.3.2 behavior.
if ( traditional === undefined ) {
    traditional = jQuery.ajaxSettings && jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional;
}
```

Code at line 7403 of jquery.js (line 7403 is the one with "this.trigger"):

```
jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
    return arguments.length > 0 ?
        this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
        this.trigger( name );
    };
});
```

Code at line 6875 of jquery.js:

```
// gets hook for the prefixed version
// followed by the unprefixed version
hooks = jQuery.cssHooks[ name ] || jQuery.cssHooks[ origName ];
```

Code at line 6601 of jquery.js (line 6601 is the one with delete "elem[ internalKey ];"):

```
// IE does not allow us to delete expando properties from nodes,
// nor does it have a removeAttribute function on Document nodes;
// we must handle all of these cases
if ( deleteExpando ) {
    delete elem[ internalKey ];
   } else if ( typeof elem.removeAttribute !== core_strundefined ) {
        elem.removeAttribute( internalKey );
   } else {
    elem[ internalKey ] = null;
   }
```

Comment: Your jQuery line numbers do not match up. Your error message shows a stack trace, but none of the lines you're pointing to call any functions. What's on line 114 in main.js?

Comment: yes issue seems to be in main.js not in jquery lib.

Comment: What is at main.js that is causing the error?

Comment: I'll edit that into my response, hold on one second.

Edit:  Okay the code from main.js is now included in the original post.

Comment: What version of jquery? I think typeahead is compatible with 1.9+

Comment: You're not loading the `typeahead` plugin correctly. Check it's `<script>` tag is after jQuery but before `main.js`. Check the path in your browser to check it's not a 404.

Comment: Should be jQuery 1.9.1; Here's the script tag I'm using for it:

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: As the errors says, `$('.example-typeahead').typeahead` is `undefined`. You have to include the plugin properly. Not much we can do about it.

Comment: I believe that the plugin came with Bootstrap's JS (although I could certainly be wrong about that).  I'll try downloading it again right now and adding it to my files.

Comment: @user2421349: it's a separate plugin; http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: Got it Matt; thank you all.  I'm in the process of placing including it now.